# Creating a tuple of tuples from a list of lists

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of lists of len 20 and I wanted to **dynamically** create a tuple of tuples of the same size from it because tuples are a bit faster,
so I have a list that is something like

```
 my_list=[[1,2,3,4],[5,7,8,9],[7,8,5,3]]
```

and I want to create a tuple that is like this

```
my_tuple=((1,2,3,4),(5,7,8,9),(7,8,5,3))
```

I tried  doing

```
>>> my_tuple=tuple(my_list)

>>> ([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 5, 3])
```

and doing

```
>>> for i in my_list:
        my_tuple=my_tuple+tuple(i)

>>> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 5, 3)
```

so I resulted into creating the tuple by hard coding the indices of the lists items like

```
my_tuple=tuple((tuple(my_list[0]),tuple(my_list[1]),tuple(my_list[2])))
```

is there a way I can create the tuple dynamically since its very long??

Comment: Tuples are not exactly *a bit faster*. They are a different type of object, one that disallows changes (they are immutable). Use them when you need that property, not because they might be faster. That is premature optimisation.

Answer (score 4):

Simply

```
>>> my_tuple = tuple(tuple(i) for i in my_list)
>>> print my_tuple
((1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 7, 8, 9), (7, 8, 5, 3))
```

Concerning your assertion that tuples are "faster", you should profile your code and weigh any possible gains against the cost of the conversion. Typically I would use a `tuple` when I need an immutable collection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
>>>tuple(map(tuple, my_list))
((1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 7, 8, 9), (7, 8, 5, 3))
```

Comment: I originally down-voted because you were producing a list of tuples. I replaced the down-vote with an up-vote after the correction.

Comment: not got the time to edit. Fast downvoting :p

Comment: Although note that converting to a `tuple` from the `list` generated by the `map` function is needlessly inefficient.